# popup is not working in .net

Tags: jquery, popup

I've got a form and I want a modal to fire when the submit button is clicked. I'm using the Zurb Reveal.js plugin, and am calling jQuery and the relevant reveal.js.

my html code:

```
<input type="submit" data-reveal-id="myModal" id="popupId" value="" />
```

js code:

```
$('input[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
 $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
});
```

I have changed the code 'input[data-reveal-id]' insted of 'a[data-reveal-id]'. It working fine in html page or in php. But, when i am integrating it in .net its not working
Any solution,

Thanks

Comment: your asp.net layout page may be inserting extra JS files which may be conflicting with each other

Comment: Check for the errors by `Inspect Element`

Comment: [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is dead. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead.

Comment: @BlackSheep What is living pls mention..!

Comment: try .on() insted of .live()

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution for my question.

I used this code

```
$("#myModal").reveal();
```

where #myModal is the ID of the div which should be popup.

Thanks